# Mediatr: IRequestPostProcessor does not run after IRequestExceptionHandler

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, mediatr, mediator

Full reproduction: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AvoV1L

```cs
using System;
using MediatR;
using MediatR.Pipeline;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Ardalis.Result;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddMediatR(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblies(typeof(EnableLdapAccountCommand).Assembly);
            cfg.AddOpenRequestPostProcessor(typeof(StepRecorderingRequestPostProcessor<,>));
        });
        
        services.AddTransient<IRequestHandler<EnableLdapAccountCommand, Result>, EnableLdapAccountHandler>();
        services.AddTransient<IRequestHandler<DisableLdapAccountCommand, Result>, DisableLdapAccountHandler>();

        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        var mediator = provider.GetRequiredService<IMediator>();

        var correlationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        List<IWorkflowCommand> steps = new List<IWorkflowCommand>();
        steps.Add(new EnableLdapAccountCommand
        {
            SAMAccountName = "EnableMe",
            CorrelationId = correlationId,
        });     
        steps.Add(new DisableLdapAccountCommand
        {
            SAMAccountName = "DisableMe",
            CorrelationId = correlationId,
        });     

        var results = new List<IResult>();
        foreach (var step in steps)
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await mediator.Send(step);
                results.Add((IResult)response);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Global unhandled exception. {e.Message}");
            }
        }

        results.Dump();
    }
}

public interface IWorkflowCommand
{
    public string CorrelationId { get; set; }
}

public class DisableLdapAccountCommand : IRequest<Result>, IWorkflowCommand
{
    public string SAMAccountName { get; set; }

    public string CorrelationId { get; set; }
}

public class EnableLdapAccountCommand : IRequest<Result>, IWorkflowCommand
{
    public string SAMAccountName { get; set; }

    public string CorrelationId { get; set; }
}

public class EnableLdapAccountHandler : IRequestHandler<EnableLdapAccountCommand, Result>
{
    public Task<Result> Handle(EnableLdapAccountCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new Exception("EnableLdapAccountCommand Exception");
    }
}

public class DisableLdapAccountHandler : IRequestHandler<DisableLdapAccountCommand, Result>
{
    public Task<Result> Handle(DisableLdapAccountCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Result.Success());
    }
}

public class StepRecorderingRequestPostProcessor<TRequest, TResponse> : IRequestPostProcessor<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IWorkflowCommand
    where TResponse : Result
{
    public Task Process(TRequest request, TResponse response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        $"Post-Ran: ({request.GetType().Name}) {response.Status}".Dump();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class GenericRequestExceptionHandler<TRequest, TResponse, TException> : IRequestExceptionHandler<TRequest, TResponse, TException>
    where TRequest : IWorkflowCommand
    where TResponse : Result
    where TException : Exception
{
    public Task Handle(
        TRequest request,
        TException exception,
        RequestExceptionHandlerState<TResponse> state,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GenericRequestExceptionHandler translating exception to error.");
        var translatedResponse = Result.Error("Unhandled exception.");
        state.SetHandled((TResponse)translatedResponse); // ??? What is this error? There is a constraint that says TResponse is type of Result. So why does this mnot work?!?
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And this somehow fixes it (paste into the above fiddle):

```cs
cfg.AddOpenBehavior(typeof(I_Somehow_Cause_The_Post_Handler_To_Work<,>)); // !  This somehow causes StepRecorderingRequestPostProcessor to run now?!?!

// ...

public class I_Somehow_Cause_The_Post_Handler_To_Work<TRequest, TResponse> : RequestExceptionProcessorBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
{
    public I_Somehow_Cause_The_Post_Handler_To_Work(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        : base(serviceProvider)
    {
    }
}
```

Pulling my hair out trying to figure out how that empty `AddOpenBehavior` fixes the problem.

Also some people have said to me "Of course the post handler doesn't run, your code encountered an exception."

The exception is explicitly handled and a result is returned. For me this is important because I would expect my post processor to wrap up auditing, close transactions, etc. Plus that explanation doesn't make sense when my hack makes the post handler work.

Comment: that might be a bug, you could consider adding an issue in github

Comment: @DanielA.White I did a couple days ago, no reply yet. Was posting here in case someone from the wider community could help.